# Converting Mapinfo's TAB without knowing its projection?

Tags: gdal, mapinfo, ogr2ogr

I've got a multiple sets of Mapinfo files (*.dat, *.id, *.map, *.tab). But I don't know its projections. When I'm trying `ogrinfo -al file.tab` I'm getting:

```
INFO: Open of `file.tab'
      using driver `MapInfo File' successful.

Geometry: Unknown (any)
Extent: (-43996.600000, 28383.340000) - (57101.880000, 167741.110000)
Layer SRS WKT:
LOCAL_CS["Nonearth",
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

How can I reproject it to WGS84 or something?

Comment: If they're in the same general location, like country, or other administrative unit, please edit your question with the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Nonearth' is MapInfo terminology for a standard mathematical coordinate system. This means that the data hasn't been bound to a projection/coordinate system and therefor it's not possible to directly reproject it to WGS84.

If the coordinates stored in the MAP files are matching the coordinates from a true coordinate system, you can "force" a projection onto the table and then reproject the table to a different coordinate system.

If not, you need to "move" the data to their correct position in a projected table before being able to reproject the data.